# Using Linux on Virtual Box as primary workspace?

Tags: virtualbox

I will be getting a new Windows computer for work but am interested in doing as much of my actual work as possible (emails, Office Libre, basic data analysis and Python scripting with Anaconda) via a Linux virtual box. Let’s say my new computer comes with 8-12 gigs of RAM and a 256 gig hard drive. Should I be allocating as much as possible of those resources to the VM since I’m not expecting/hoping to do much with the Windows setup? In other words, what considerations are there in making a Linux VM my primary computing workspace?

Comment: Why not moving to Linux entirely? What about dual booting?
Is there any reason that you need Windows for?>

Comment: You can change the allocated RAM from one boot to the other. For the hard drive, Virtual Box as a specific format where only the memory used is allocated to the host system. In short, it is not a big deal.

Comment: @ZektorH my org has policies that require Windows for certain functions which is why I can’t switch fully. I will look up the difference between dual boot and VM with Linux but if you have any additional thoughts on that I’d love to know. Thank you in any case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can allocate disk space dynamically, so that it won't take more than is needed. Memory can be adjusted easily, so start with the recommended value and adjust as required. Start with a minimal Linux install and add what you need for your work. This arrangement works well, and you can used the shared drive feature so that you can edit files in the VM using the native Windows tools if desired. I find it is very handy for trying out distros and applications that you can blow away later.

Comment: Thank you that is very helpful.